# String-array is not populating in spinner when viewing Design

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, android-spinner

I have added a string-array of "distance" in my string.xml with a list of different distances and applied it within a Spinner in my second activity. I've also incorporated the Spinner in the second activities java folder. The problem I'm having is the distances are not populating in my spinner in the design. I don't know if the coding in Java is incorrect and is the reason it is not being displayed.

This is the strings.xml:

```
<string name="distancetravel">Distance willing to travel?</string>
<string-array name="distance">
    <item>Within 20 miles</item>
    <item>Within 50 miles</item>
    <item>Within 100 miles</item>
    <item>Endless Miles</item>
</string-array>
```

This is the activity2.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/distancelist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/distance"
    android:layout_below="@+id/distancetravel"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Activity2.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);

        spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.distance,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time if R is not found then the issue is with the project itself and something is not resolving correctly. Try to clean and rebuild the project and see if R can be resolved. If that doesn't work, try passing it your array declared as a string array like so

```
String[] foo_array = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.foo_array);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I have tried to clean the project and it doesn't help. I'm new to this, so wasn't sure where to put:             String[] foo_array = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.foo_array);           In the strings section or java and do I have to incorporate the distances I need in this string ?

Comment: Hmm next I would try maybe your import statements to make sure nothing is miss named. You would place that in your java code as String[] foo_array is declaring a new java string and mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.foo_array); is pulling your array from your resources.

Comment: Thank you! The red R. on java went away. Now the only issue I'm having is my Spinner is not displaying the stringed distances in the Design view. Any ideas why? It just shows the default spinner with "Item1 and Sub Item1".

Comment: woot ! thats great. Hmmm I am not sure about that one I actually never use spinners but if I had to guess I would say it has something to do with the XML. Try to follow the example on the dev docs here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html. and remember to mark as correct answer ~(0_0)~.